# Is there any way to use /enchant on a book in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to `/enchant` a book, but it's not working. Is there any way to do this in v1.14 +?

My command is

```
/enchant @p mending
```

and it is hooked up to a comparator to tell me when it works.

Whenever I run the command, it says "*book can not support this enchantment*".
I've searched the internet for similar results but cannot find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

`/enchant` does not work on the stored enchantments of books. You can only use an enchanting table or anvil or set it directly in NBT like this:

```
/give @s enchanted_book{StoredEnchantments:[{id:"mending",lvl:1}]}
```

Comment: great! i think it works on bedrock though. thanks for the awnser!

Comment: No, it doesn't. MCBE has no NBT in commands.

Comment: i meant /enchant @p mending will apply it to a book.